# Python: Max retries exceeded with URL in requests

Tags: python

I am trying to download data using pdr from the St. Louis FRED.

```
fred = pdr.DataReader(['GS10', 'INDPRO'], 'fred', '2000', '2019')
fred
```

However, I am getting the following error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fred.stlouisfed.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /graph/fredgraph.csv?id=GS10 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002328B189520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is unclear about this message? It seems based on what you've provided here that the server you're attempting to contact didn't send a complete response within your configured timeout period. Unless you own the destination server that isn't sending the response completely/properly/at all, or any of the intermediary network infrastructure that's intercepting this request/response for whatever reason, I fail to see what you *could* do to prevent this. Can you access the resource from the same device/network segment using a browser or an HTTP client?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more the context please ? Give us a part of the code that you run. With that perhaps I could help you.

Comment: I attached my codes in the question, thank you